# Like SQL Statement SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query but I have mutiple records I need to filter out. I'm using the like statment with wild cards. Is there a better way do do this then writing out each one? Can I create a udf, table that it refrences? How? If I can. Thanks :)

```
SELECT a.SalesOrderNo ,
       a.ShipExpireDate ,
       a.CustomerNo ,
       b.ItemCode ,
       b.LineKey ,
       b.QuantityOrdered ,
       b.QuantityShipped ,
       b.ItemCodeDesc ,
       b.ExplodedKitItem
FROM dbo.SO_SalesOrderHeader a
LEFT JOIN dbo.SO_SalesOrderDetail b
ON a.SalesOrderNo = b.SalesOrderNo
WHERE b.ItemType = '1'
  AND b.ItemCodeDesc NOT LIKE '%Cert%'
  AND b.ItemCodeDesc NOT LIKE '%Fee%'
  AND b.ItemCodeDesc NOT LIKE '%Tag%'
  AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE 'GF%'
  AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE 'PXDIALPREP'
  AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE '/C%'
  AND a.ShipExpireDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 101)
```

Comment: Can you explain why your aliases are `a` and `b`? Wouldn't `h` (for `header`) and `d` (for `detail`) make 10,000,000 % more sense?

Comment: Also converting to DATE with a style number makes little sense. If you want all the `ShipExpireDate` values that expire today at any time, use `CONVERT(DATE, ShipExpireDate) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`. Usually you would not be very wise to apply `CONVERT` to the column but this is the one case where it is still sargable (which means it will still use an index on that column, if one exists).

Comment: Yes h  and d makes much more sense. I'll be using that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different design that lets you put ItemCodeDesc in a seperate table (this could also be a TVF). I can't comment on performance though.

On a different note, be aware that because you are outer joining to sales order detail, this table can have NULL records. In turn your `b.ItemType = '1'` will always be FALSE when ItemType is NULL. So you may as well make it an inner join (and you might find your query plan is doing that anyway)

```
   SELECT a.SalesOrderNo ,
   a.ShipExpireDate ,
   a.CustomerNo ,
   b.ItemCode ,
   b.LineKey ,
   b.QuantityOrdered ,
   b.QuantityShipped ,
   b.ItemCodeDesc ,
   b.ExplodedKitItem
   FROM dbo.SO_SalesOrderHeader a
   LEFT JOIN dbo.SO_SalesOrderDetail b
   ON a.SalesOrderNo = b.SalesOrderNo
   WHERE b.ItemType = '1'
   AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE 'GF%'
   AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE 'PXDIALPREP'
   AND b.ItemCode NOT LIKE '/C%'
   AND a.ShipExpireDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 101) 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MappingTable MT 
        WHERE b.ItemCodeDesc LIKE MT.ItemCodeDesc
        )
```

Comment: +1 for the observation that this is an INNER JOIN, not an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am guessing that your criteria is meant to filter out item types that can't be shipped (like Fees), adjust as per your requirements.

The problem you are encountering is a result of discrete values being stored in an ID.  Looks like you should have a column IsShippable, or better yet a code table for ItemCodeType with rows of Cert, Fee, Tag, etc. and the IsShippable column there.   if you had a code table then you'd be able to do

```
inner join ItemCodeTypes ict on ict.ItemCodeTypeId = b.ItemCodeTypeId and ict.IsShippable = 1
```

Cert, Fee, Tag, rows in the ItemCodeTypes table would have IsShippable = 0:

```
Id | Name |  IsShippable
1    Cert    0
2    Fee     0
3    Tag     0
4    Product 1
5    Book    1
```

**Edit:** To more directly answer your question, you could make a view like this, and then when you query from it easily filter on Where IsShippable = 1:

```
Select CASE 
  When b.ItemCodeDesc LIKE '%Cert%' Then 0
  When b.ItemCodeDesc LIKE '%Fee%' Then 0 
--etc.
  Else 1
END as IsShippable
,* 
From dbo.SO_SalesOrderDetail
```

Comment: Thanks for everyones quick response.